# Is there a way to add an individual to our block list?

Tags: feature-request

There are times when I start losing patience with an individual and the best thing for both of us and for the general conversation is if I don't respond to them -- and ideally if I don't even see what they're writing so I'm not tempted to respond -- for a while.

In newsgroups, this was the function of the killfile. Many, but not all, other social media offer something similar.

Does Stack Exchange have any way to achieve that effect?

Comment: I'm surprised yesterday's post was removed. I thought it raised a legitimate question and if nothing else, we should talk about the abuse of self-answers...

Answer (score -2):

Stack Exchange unfortunately doesn't have this feature natively. Related posts:

- [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/178179) (feature request on Meta + some possible solutions)
- [Browser extension to hide all the activities of a given user on Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3399/903)